# Moto E - Auto switching off/on

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, motorola-moto-e

I have a Moto E which is only a few days old. It keeps switching off and on all day, automatically and usually around 20 times each day. It supports up to 32GB memory card, and I'm using a 32 GB card (if this might causing problem).

Comment: The question is too general. Did you have the issue when you used the phone for the first time ? Did you install any applications just before the issue started ? Did you try a phone reset ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the culprit is an app. Try safe mode. Press the Power button and when the menu pops up tap and hold on the Power off option and then tap OK. If you don’t experience any random reboots in safe mode then we can assume that one of the apps you’ve installed is responsible for the reboots.

Read more: [10 tricky Moto E problems and how to fix them | Digital Trends](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/moto-e-problems/#ixzz3GPecbzVY)

Comment: Please disclose if you are affiliated with the linked article.

Answer (score -3):

It's probably a problem with one of your SIM cards. Whenever your phone restarts, it is because there is no network for one of your SIMs. So it restarts which may get network.

If you are using 3g network, try changing it to 2g.

Comment: `Whenever your phone restarts, it is because there is no network for one of your SIMs.` I can think of many more reasons for a phone to restart.

Comment: I've never heard a phone restarting deliberately just to get the mobile network. That will be certainly annoying for end-users.